# Heroku Node.js bot deployment failed

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

[image: 1]

I ran into a problem while uploading the bot on Heroku.
The essence of the bot is simple. 24/7 radio on a given link.

On the computer, the bot works absolutely fine. But as soon as I upload it to Heroku, it stops working.

Comment: We need to see your code in app.js to help you. Btw why do you use "discord.js-extended" instead of https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.